# Identify this old C64 soccer game with "speaker"

Tags: commodore-64, identify-this-game

In "modern" games (Fifa 98, Fifa 2000, PES, etc) you can hear the speaker talking about the match.

This was near impossible in the C64 era, but I remember a soccer game that had a speaker with a phone and microphone which appear when you scored a goal and "said" "nice shoot!" or something similar. Of course you can not hear the voice because it was text only and the speaker appeared in the left upper (or lower, I don't remember) part of the screen.

Does someone know the title of this game?

It's NOT: Kickoff, Microprose soccer or Sensible world of soccer

Comment: Is it possible it's "World Cup Soccer: Italy 90'" as seen here? https://youtu.be/X0leg6eAB9k?t=437

Comment: No is not it, I cannot see the speaker with phones and microphone

Comment: I think I remember a game like this from an 8-Bit Guy video…

Comment: Kick-Off and Sensible World of Soccer were Amiga games - are you sure it's a C64 game? OSG did a video showcasing a lot of C64 Soccer games, maybe it's in there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrWTReCzrH8

Comment: Sure 100% because I play it in my only home computer of 80 which was c64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it, thanks to user [Michael](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/3344/michael-stum) which in comment report the youtube video which contain the game.
Its name was "Fighting Soccer" 1989 from Activision

[image]

In the pic you can see the image of "speaker", the earphones and microphones was a bad game of my mind after a lot of years (33 years ago!)

Another soccer game with speaker (this time with hearphones, like a real speaker) was I Play 3D Soccer (1991)
the speaker seems to be repeating in loop the same words for every seconds of game.

[image]